# program crashing

Tags: c++

I m newbie to programming. Please help me with this question.

when i execute this program, program will crash. can anybody tell me the exact reason for the crash?

```
#include<stdio.h>    
#include<string.h>    
#include<vector>    
using namespace std;    

struct s  
{  
    char *str;  
};  

std::vector<struct s> v;  
int main()  
{  
    struct s s1;  
    strcpy(s1.str,"hi");  
    v.push_back(s1);  
    strcpy(s1.str,"hello");  
    v.push_back(s1);  
    strcpy(s1.str,"How are you");  
    v.push_back(s1);  
    strcpy(s1.str,"AMAZING");  
    v.push_back(s1);  
    for (int i=0;i<(int)v.size();i++)  
    {           
        printf("%s\n",v[i].str);  
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

i am compiling it in devc++.
pls help.

Comment: #1 what shall your program accomplish
#2 what is the error code

Comment: use __declspec(align(16)) char[] to make it faster

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: wtf? First of all, that is very compiler specific, second of all forcing alignment will often make your program slower, not faster, third of all: this is a newbie question about a crash, not some advanced optimization question :s.

Comment: @KillianDS: OMG? He is newbie and started from vectors & pointers? VC++ 10.0 express 's strlen(char * str) includes a loop that checks if str is aligned. Making str aligned in the declaration makes strlen-like functions work faster for some small-length strings.

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: automatic storage and dynamic storage (using new) should be aligned correctly without specification. specifying an alignment can result in something sub-optimal for your specific platform.

Comment: i didnt know that "new" was making it aligned. thanks. is it same with calloc malloc alloc?

Answer (score 3):

No memory has been allocated for `str` and `struct s` is [violating the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three): use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead.

You don't need to specify `struct s` (you do in C) when declaring a type of `s`, just use `s`:

```
std::vector<s> v;

s s1;
```

You could make `struct s` more convenient to use by providing a constructor:

```
struct s
{
    s(const std::string& a_s) : str(a_s) {}
    std::string str;
};

v.push_back(s("hi"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't allocated any memory for `s1.str` to point at. You're writing via an unitialized pointer, giving undefined behavior.

Try something like:

```
struct s { 
    std::string str;
};

s s1;

s1.str = "hi";
v.push_back(s1);
// etc.
```

better still, just use a string directly, and a C++11 initializer list:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{"hi", "hello", "how are you", "AMAZING"};

std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocated memory for `char *str;` in your struct

just take a look at the `strcpy` documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/

The memory were you are copying must be allocated. But when you write:

```
char *str;
```

memory is not allocated. You've just created a pointer (to garbage)

You can allocated the memory or better use `std::string`, because memory management will be done for you in that case

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating memory in `s.str`.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing Undefined Behavior. Your `char * str` is just a pointe,r with no memory allocated. Nevertheless, you try to modify the memory it points to. Since that memory doesn't belong to your program, you are getting a crash.

Since it's UB, you can't really tell what *will* happen. For example, for me this code runs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for s1, before using it (uniniatialized pointers point to garbage).. use `new` for that once done don't forget to release the memory using `delete` operator..

I suggest you to have a look in some good C++ tutorials,

1. [see this link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial.html)
2. [Another good C++ resource](http://www.cpp4u.com/c++/tutorial/beginner.html)

**Note** I have edited (changed) this answer since all others answer correctly address the problem. I just wanted to add few cents to them.

Comment: mallocs and c-style casts in a C++ program? That's not something you should learn to a novice programmer. You even forgot the `free`'s. Also, you do not need to allocate memory for `s1`, it's an automatic storage variable.

Comment: @KillianDS good points... I actually didn't notice that its C++ program... #stupidMe... updating my answer for that.... Thanks